# Extract serial number from string by using regex in c#

Tags: c#

Serial Number :- **4540107708_E4-UR730RSQ_XICM_1**

Code (C#):-

```
string Pattern = "^[0-9]{1,10}_[a-z0-9A-Z-]{2,12}_XICM_[0-9]$";

string inputStr = "Abcd Abcdefg Abcdefghij xyzyzxue, 4540107708_E4-UR730RSQ_XICM_1 abcdefg Abcd Abcdefg Abcdefghij xyzyzxue."; 

Regex regex = new Regex(Pattern,RegexOptions.None);

Match match = regex.Match(inputStr);

if (match.Success)
{
   string matchValue = match.Value;
   Console.WriteLine(matchValue);
   Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

i want this serial number (4540107708_E4-UR730RSQ_XICM_1) from inputStr.

please help..

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5oXm.png)

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` anchors. Or [replace with `\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5b0-9%5d%7b1%2c10%7d_%5ba-z0-9A-Z-%5d%7b2%2c12%7d_XICM_%5b0-9%5d%5cb&i=Abcd+Abcdefg+Abcdefghij+xyzyzxue%2c+4540107708_E4-UR730RSQ_XICM_1+abcdefg+Abcd+Abcdefg+Abcdefghij+xyzyzxue.).

Comment: https://regex101.com/

Comment: thanks Wiktor Stribiżew . it works after removing anchors.

Answer (score 1):

The `^` anchor requires the match to appear at the start of the string and `$` requires the match to appear at the end of the string. What you need is to find the match as a whole word. Use word boundaries:

```
\b[0-9]{1,10}_[a-z0-9A-Z-]{2,12}_XICM_[0-9]\b
^^                                         ^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C10%7D_%5Ba-z0-9A-Z-%5D%7B2%2C12%7D_XICM_%5B0-9%5D%5Cb&i=Abcd%20Abcdefg%20Abcdefghij%20xyzyzxue%2C%204540107708_E4-UR730RSQ_XICM_1%20abcdefg%20Abcd%20Abcdefg%20Abcdefghij%20xyzyzxue.)